# CodeDeploy detected that the Lambda function alias' ProvisionedConcurrency is in Failed status

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-code-deploy

Has anyone come across this before? It seems like whatever is causing the Lambda containers to become unhealthy is buried under high level error:

`CodeDeploy detected that the Lambda function alias' ProvisionedConcurrency is in Failed status.`

Also, is there any way I can see why it's failing? I can roll my change back but that doesn't really help root cause the issue.